# $c\exp(ch(x_c))$ for $x_c\to 0$ and $h(x_c)=O(x_c^2)$ as $c\to\infty$

Tags: analysis

Consider the polynomial $p_c(x)=x^{c+1}-x^c-1$. Its largest (unique) positive root $\lambda_c$ can be shown to be contained in the open interval $(1,1+\frac{\ln c}{c})$, but I want to determine more exactly what happens with $\lambda_c$ as $c\to\infty$.

Since the right interval bound tends to $1$ as $c\to\infty$, the idea is to write

$\lambda_c=1+x_c$ for some zero sequence $(x_c)$, $\lim_{c\to\infty}x_c=0$.

Putting $\lambda_c=1+x_c$ into $p_c$, and applying the logarithm, one gets

$$
c\ln(1+x_c)+\ln(x_c)=cx_c+cg(x_c)+\ln(x_c)=0,
$$
where I used the approximation $\ln(1+x_c)=x_c+g(x_c)$ with $g(x_c)=O(x_c^2)$ as $c\to\infty$ which works since $x_c\to 0$ as $c\to\infty$.

Exponentiation and multiplication with $c$ gives
$$
cx_ce^{cx_c}=ce^{-cg(x_c)}=ce^{ch(x_c)},
$$
where $h(x_c)=O(x_c^2), c\to\infty$.

Using Lambert's W-function, this yields
$$
x_c=\frac{1}{c} W(ce^{ch(x_c)})
$$

> > In order to use the large argument approximation of $W$, I would like to argue that, for large $c$,
> >     $$
> > c\exp(ch(x_c))\geq c.
> > $$

I think this boils down to show that, for large $c$,
$$
ch(x_c)\geq 0
$$
since this would immediately imply $\exp(ch(x_c))\geq 1$ for large $c$ and hence I could use that
$$
W(c\exp(ch(x_c)))=\ln(c\exp(ch(x_c)))-\ln\ln(c\exp(ch(x_c)))+o(1).
$$
as $c\to\infty$.

Unfortunately, I did not manage to show this (although I think its correct). Maybe you can give me some help.

Comment: If there are no additional conditions on $x_n$ and $f$, the answer is of course negative (take $x_n = n^{-1/4}$ and $f(x) = -x^2$, say).

Comment: I see. What for conditions might that be and where is the mistake in my "proof"?

Comment: How do I know? Ultimately required is something more explicit on $x_n$ as a function of $n$.

Comment: A mistake is stating that $|nf(x_n)| = nf(x_n)$.

Comment: I only state this for large $n$ since $f(x_n)=O(x_n^2), n\to\infty$.

Comment: Look at my counterexample - the statement fails for _all_ $n$, and any negative $f$ would do that.

Comment: @Rhjg "big Oh" only talks about the absolute value, so it doesn't care if $f$ is positive or negative

Comment: What if I have the additional condition that $nx_n+nf(x_n)+\ln(x_n)=0$? This is a equation which is the only extra condition which I can see in my context (sorry for forgetting to mention it).

Comment: And maybe I should have remarked that the function $f(x_n)=O(x_n^2)$ comes from the approx of the logarithm, $\ln(1+x_n)=x_n+f(x_n)$.

Comment: Please put everything into the question itself - otherwise it looks like you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: I completely reformulated and completed my question such that the background is clear now.

Comment: I dont think so: $p_c(1+x_c)=(1+x_c)^c((1+x_c)-1)-1=(1+x_c)^cx_c-1=0$, hence $c\ln(1+x_c)+\ln(x_c)=0$

Comment: Ah, of course, I had forgotten you were working with $p_c(\lambda_c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boiling it down, you want to show that $h(x_c) \ge 0$ for $c$ large.  In fact, the situation is even better than that:

> $h(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

To see this, notice that $h(x) = -g(x)$, where $g$ is the remainder term in the expansion
$$\log(1+x) = x + g(x)$$
so we only need to show $g(x) \le 0$.  But, this follows from the concavity of $\log$:
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left.\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(1+x)\right|_{x = \xi}x^2 = -\frac{x^2}{2(1+\xi)^2} \qquad \text{for some } \xi \in (0, x).$$

Comment: Maybe I get your answer wrong but you basically say that g(x) is the term with the second derivative in the Taylor expansion of ln(1+x). But my understanding was that g(x) sums up all the terms of order 2 and higher.

Comment: @Rhjg I'm using the Lagrange form for the remainder of a Taylor series.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Only a minor question. Isn't it $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2 }{dx^2}\ln(x)_{|x=\xi}x^2=-\frac{x^2}{2\xi^2}\leq 0$ for some $\xi\in (1,1+x)$? I don't see why you are differentiating $\ln(1+x)$ and not only $\ln(x)$.

Comment: @Rhjg The function is $\ln(1+x)$ because we are expanding $\ln(1+x) = 0 + x + g(x)$.  We could equally well do $\ln(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1) + \tilde{g}(\lambda)$, and then we would have
$g(x) = - \frac{(\lambda - 1)^2}{2\xi^2}$ for $\xi \in (1, 1+x)$ where $\lambda = 1+x$, but this would be a different expansion.

Comment: I would prefer to use the expansion where $x_0=1$ is the point we are expanding in, i.e. $g(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2\xi^2}$ for $\xi\in (1,1+x)$.

Comment: What irritates me is that in the Taylot expansion $\ln(1+x)=x+g(x)$, the term $g(x)=O(x^2)$ as $x\to\infty$, while $g(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2\xi^2}$ for $\xi\in (1,1+x)$ says that $g(x)=O(x^2)$ for all $x$ but I guess that has to do with the fact that in the first case the infinite taylor series is consider while in the second $g(x)$ is only representing the second order remainder.  - - Therefore my question is whether it is really justified to use the Lagrange-formula for $g(x)$ here because g(x) seems to have two different meanings here

Comment: @Rhjg The term $g$ is *not* $O(x^2)$ as $x \to \infty$.  (in fact, it is $O(x)$ as $x \to \infty$, since $\ln x$ is negligible compared to $x$ in this limit).  Remember that $\xi$ depends on $x$.  The function $g$ is $O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$, however.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. We have that $g(x)=O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$.  - - The dependence $\xi=\xi(x)$ makes $g(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2\xi(x)^2}=O(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$ and not for all $x$ as I said? How?